# How to get the return value of the shell command executed in a linux kernel module?

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

everyone!

I want to get the return value of the shell command "ls" in a kernel module.
the following is the source code of my kernel module.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("yuuyuu");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("kernel module hello");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");

static int hello_init(void)
{

    char * envp[] = { "HOME=/", NULL };
    char * argv[] = { "/bin/ls","/home", NULL };

    call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);

    printk(KERN_ALERT "hello_init() start\n");
    return 0;
}


static void hello_exit(void)
{
printk(KERN_ALERT "hello_exit() start\n");
}


module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Is there anyone know how to get the output of "ls /home"?

Thanks!

Comment: So do you want to get **return value** of shell command or its **output**? These are different things. *Return value* of the user space program can be obtained as return value of `call_usermodehelper`. As for *output* of the user space program, there is no simple way to get it in the kernel. Actually, `call_usermodehelper` executes user space program without terminal, so no output is collected. You may try redirect output of the command into the file, which you are previously created in the kernel module.

Comment: Thanks, Tsyvarev! I want to get the output of "sha1sum filename". How to redirct output of the command?

Comment: Instead of the `ls` command you may execute shell and pass it appropriate string. This string may contain output redirection. E.g., use these `argv` : `{"/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/ls /home > <path-to-file>", NULL}`.